# Carregamento lento com plugin JQuery DataTables

Tags: jquery, laravel, jquery-datatables

Estou usando o JQuery DataTables em um pequeno sistema e estava tudo muito bem até que me deparei com uma listagem de quase 2500 registros...

A questão é que demora um certo tempo até que as informações sejam carregadas e ajustadas no DataTable, o que faz com que fique carregando e exibindo todos os 2500 registros na página até que carregue tudo e a paginação entre em ação.

Teria alguma forma de evitar/mascarar isso? Atualmente não uso ajax, faço assim:

**No meu Controller:**

```
public function index()
{
    $funcoes = Funcao::orderBy('id')->get();
    return view('cadastros/funcao/index', compact('funcoes'));
}
```

**Na minha View:**

```
<table id="appDatatable" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead><tr><th>...</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($funcoes as $funcao)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $funcao->cbo }}</td>
        <td>{{ $funcao->nome }}</td>
        ...
    </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Meu script:**

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#appDatatable").DataTable({
            sPaginationType: "simple_numbers",
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Um opção seria você carregar pelos eventos/interações do usuario com a tabela. https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Comment: Carregar 2500 registros de uma só vez não é sensato, por que não usar Server-side processing? https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Comment: Eu n uso por que eu não sei mesmo rs, vou dar uma olhada nesse link e ver se consigo fazer aqui

Comment: No caso estou usando Laravel5, na parte que chama o ajax eu ponho uma rota que devolva os elementos todos em JSON e ele faz esse lance de carregar só o que precisa?

Comment: A chamada ajax está dentro do método .DataTable? ou você preenche a <table> primeiro e depois usa $('#tabela').DataTable()?

Comment: isso, eu preencho e depois chamo

Comment: edita a pergunta e coloca o javascript da chamada ajax e do .DataTable()

Comment: coloquei o que faço atualmente @EduardoMoreira

Comment: olha, essa lerdeza provavelmente é na escrita da tabela, e não em você transformar ela em DataTable (na minha experiência isso é bem rápido). sugiro que você teste sem transformar ela em DataTable para confirmar onde está o problema.

Comment: Sim, pelo visto está lento por seu muita coisa mesmo, também demorou bastante sem o DataTable, vou tentar fazer o que disseram com o server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu já passei por esse problema. Percebi que a lerdeza era causada por eu preencher manualmente a tabela e, depois, usar $('#tabela').DataTable(). Vejo duas alternativas para resolver isso, mas ambas precisam de ajax.

A primeira opção, mais fácil, é fazer uma chamada ajax e entregar o json ao DataTables

Portanto:

```
function preencherTabela(jsonData) {
    $('#tabela').DataTable({
        destroy: true, //retirar essa linha caso você nunca recarregar a tabela
        sPaginationType: "simple_numbers",
        data: jsonData,
        columns: [
            { "data": "Cbo" },
            { "data": "Nome" }
        ]
    });
}

$.ajax({
    url: '/suaUrl',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (jsonData) {
        preencherTabela (jsonData);
    }
});
```

A segunda opção, mais elegante, seria usar o suporte a "server-side processing" e fazer uma paginação real. Particularmente nunca precisei fazer isso e portanto não posso te ajudar muito. Mais sobre o assunto [aqui](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)

Comment: tentei fazer dessa forma mas ta dando erro "Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined" na linha " success: preencherTabela (jsonData)". Esse jsonData eu tenho que substituir por algo?

Comment: tinha um probleminha no success. Editei. jsonData é só um nome qualquer que eu dei para a variável. São os dados que você vai receber via ajax para a popular a tabela (se o ajax for bem sucedido, claro).

Comment: Ah agora funcionou, já da pra quebrar um galho enquanto eu vejo como implementar esse lance do server side com mais calma, vlw.